# get raw input that is between a set of numbers with some checks

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to get the user input 2 numbers which are split into a list of 2 integers, but unfortunately I can't seem to get them to turn into integers, but I am also unsure of my checks and if it is going to terminate properly and return what I need.

```
def getlohiint():
    lohilist = []
    lohi = raw_input("Enter min and max number of points to use(e.g., 2 1000): ")
    lohilist = lohi.split()
    for x in lohilist:
        int(x)
    if lohilist[0]<=2 and lohilist[1]<=1000 and lohilist[0]<lohilist[1]:
        break
    else:
        prompt = "%d is not in the range of 2 to 1000; "
        prompt1 = "must be at least 2"
        prompt2 = "must be no higher than 1000"
        if lohilist[0]<2:
            print prompt + prompt1
        elif lohilist[1]>1000:
            print prompt + prompt2
        else:
            print prompt + prompt1 + prompt2
        lohi
    high = lohilist[1]
    low = lohilist[0]
    return(low, high)
```

Comment: but after I add lohilist = [int(x) for x in lohi.split()] I'm not sure how to do my check properly. specifically the first if loop

Comment: Did you mean the block of the first `if` statement? An `if` block is not a loop, it is only executed once. If you just went to tutorialspoint.com and saw that the `break` came after the `if` statement, it's because it was in a `for` or `while` loop in those examples. If you want to do nothing on an if statement being true, use `pass`, it's essentially a `nop`, or no operation statement (it does nothing). You can also simply put the whole if statement in parentheses and put a `not` before it and make that the error case; thus changing the `if...else` to just an `if` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never assign the result of `int(x)` to anything. It's easiest achieved with a list comprehension:

```
lohilist = [int(x) for x in lohi.split()]
```

Note that you can assign to multiple targets at once:

```
low, high = [int(x) for x in lohi.split()]
```

would convert everything in `lohi` to integers and assign to the two variables in one go.

You may want to test for exceptions too here:

```
def getlohiint():
    while True:
        lohi = raw_input("Enter min and max number of points to use(e.g., 2 1000): ")
        try:
            low, high = [int(x) for x in lohi.split()]
        except ValueError:
            # either not integers or not exactly 2 numbers entered.
            print "You must enter exactly 2 numbers here"
            continue

        if low <= 2 and high <= 1000 and low < high:
            # valid input, return
            return low, high

        if low > 2:
            print 'The minimum must be 2 or lower'
        if high > 1000:
            print 'The maximum must be 1000 or lower'
        if low >= high:
            print 'The maximum must be greater than the minimum'
```

Comment: I always forget this method...(makes me feel stupid) Thank you, but how do i do my checks properly. I don't think break is the appropriate method

Comment: I had something like this initially minus try and except, but i was still having problems with getting and integer. Why is there a try statement? Thanks you very much

Comment: The `int()` function raises `ValueError` if the string contains anything that cannot be concerted to an integer, and the multiple assignment will raise the same exception if the list comprehension on the right results in fewer or more than 2 values. The `try` statement handles either case.

Answer (score 3):

`int(x)` returns an integer value, it does not modify the value of x.

You probably want something like:

```
def getlohiint():
    lohilist = []
    lohi = raw_input("Enter min and max number of points to use(e.g., 2 1000): ")
    lohilist = lohi.split()
    lohilist = [int(x) for x in lohilist]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would abstract this out a bit: make a function that parses a list of integers from input, then another function which takes a list of integers and tests that they fit your criteria:

```
import sys

# version compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input

def get_ints(prompt, delimiter=None):
    while True:
        try:
            return [int(i) for i in inp(prompt).split(delimiter)]
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_lo_hi_ints(prompt, min_=None, max_=None):
    while True:
        try:
            lo, hi = get_ints(prompt)

            if lo >= hi:
                print("First value must be < second value")
            elif (min_ is not None and lo < min_):
                print("Low value must be >= {}".format(min_))
            elif (max_ is not None and hi > max_):
                print("High value must be <= {}".format(max_))
            else:
                return lo, hi
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter 2 values!")
```

then you can use it like

```
min_points, max_points = get_lo_hi_ints("Enter min and max number of points to use(e.g., 2 1000): ", 2, 1000)
```

Comment: Instead of the version test, just try and reference `raw_input`; if you get a `NameError`, you use `input` instead.